# Headful puppeteer: How to make page scrollable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, puppeteer

I'm running puppeteer in headful mode.

At a certain point manual user intervention is required.

However I cannot scroll the window manually. This can become a problem depending on the users screen resolution. And there are no scrollbars showing in the window.

If you run the following code, and then resize the browser with your mouse to make it smaller, scrollbars never appear.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        'height': 800,
        'width': 1300
    });
    await page.goto('https://google.com');
    await page.waitFor(60000);
    await browser.close();
});
```

I've tried changing the viewport size.

I've also tried setting the defaultViewport to null.

await puppeteer.launch({defaultViewport: null, headless: false})

So how can I make it so that the page is scrollable?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. You set the viewport to `1300x800`. At this viewport size there will be no scrollbars on google.com. If you set it to something lower like `400x400` you will see scrollbars.

Comment: I had a hard time phrasing this question. Problem is, on a users machine, when a captcha pops up, the captcha is cut off and they cannot scroll. And on google, (google is just an example) if I resize the window using my mouse on ubuntu, scrollbars appear if I set defaultViewport to null. On osx, no scroll bars appear.

Comment: I guess the problem is then that the window must have a fixed viewport. Is the viewport maybe bigger than the browser windows itself? You can change the viewport at any point by calling `setViewport` if that is the problem.